# how to go back to Main activity from any fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 5 Fragment and the user can go to any of them from **MainActivity** navigation drawer. for example, the user opens the navigation drawer and clicks on Settings. when the user presses back button it closes the app. But I wanna take the user back to MainActivity. how can I do that?

I tried all codes in StackOverflow and no one helped.
this is how I take the user to the settings fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framlayout_main, new SettingFragment(), "settings").commit();
                    Method.onBackPress = true;
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is to clear the fragment backstack, try this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for( int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, do I suppose to use this code in fragment onbackpressed?

Comment: I'd say make a function called `clearFragmentBackstack()`, paste this code into it and call I whenever you need it

Comment: please concern that i am really junior in android. I did what you say but it all going to be red and i don`t know what to do. i made a function ,  public void clearFragmentBackstack() {

        val fm = activity!!.getSupportFragmentManager()
        for (i in 0 until fm.getBackStackEntryCount()) {
            fm.popBackStack()
        }
    }

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, this is Kotlin and you need Java. I've updated my comment

Comment: Thanks, but getActivity() is still red and when I import it () will be red and says cannot resolve method getActivity();   :(

Comment: getActivity() can only be called inside a Fragment. In you Activity itself you can call getSupportFragmentManager() directly

Comment: Is there anything else to do in the fragment or change my codes? because I made this function and called it in my code and there is nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more here, I'd need to have a look at the entirety of the code.